# ParserError: Expected '{' but got 'constant'

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, ethereum-wallet-dapp, golang

This is my error message

ParserError: Expected '{' but got 'constant' --> amkcoin.sol:50:35: | 50 | function totalSupply() public constant returns (uint); | ^^^^^^^^

and this is code line..

```
}


/**
ERC Coin Standard #20 Interface
https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20-Coin-standard.md
*/
contract ERC20Interface {
    function totalSupply() public constant returns (uint);
    function balanceOf(address CoinOwner) public constant returns (uint balance);
    function allowance(address CoinOwner, address spender) public constant returns (uint remaining);
    function transfer(address to, uint Coins) public returns (bool success);
    function approve(address spender, uint Coins) public returns (bool success);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint Coins) public returns (bool success);
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint Coins);
    event Approval(address indexed CoinOwner, address indexed spender, uint Coins);
}
```

can u tell me whats wrong with totalSupply line any one can fix this line pls thanks.

Comment: Can you share the complete code from amkcoin.sol ? Thx.

Answer (score 1):

I think you got an older version of that interface and it should say `view` instead of `constant`. If I remember correctly, constant was the predecessor to view.

For more details on the ERC20 token standard refer to the EIP20 GitHub page:
https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20.md

They also link to **example implementations**. This probably helps you the most. Here you can find a new version of the ERC20Interface contract:
https://github.com/ConsenSys/Tokens/blob/fdf687c69d998266a95f15216b1955a4965a0a6d/contracts/eip20/EIP20Interface.sol